# What is the opposite of "fall out of favour" with someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

What is the opposite of "fall out of favour with someone"?

Comment: why not just "come into favour with someone"?

Comment: You need to add an explanation of what you're looking for. Otherwise, the opposite could be ***not*** fall out of favor with = remain in favor or @GEdgar's solution or several other possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To come into someone's good graces.

> in someone's good / bad graces, regarded with favor (or disfavor) by
>   someone.
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-someone-s-good-graces listed at number 20 under idioms.

If you want another one, which isn't as good:

"To get in someone's good books" which is very colloquial and informal

> in someone's good books BRITISH, INFORMAL If you are in someone's good
>   books, you have done something that has pleased them.

[Link here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+someone%27s+good+books)

Comment: A link to your reference would be useful.

Comment: I wouldn't say "to get in someone's good books" was a) not as good as your other suggestion or b) more informal than "fall out of favour". But then I'm British, and it's the obvious answer to me. +1 as it doesn't seem worth me writing a seperate answer for it.

Answer (score -1):

[Pulling the wool over someone's eyes](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+the+wool+over+eyes) is a method of gaining favor or advantage, using deception (originally it meant wearing a fancy powdered wig, to make oneself appear respectable).

It is in opposition to *falling out of favour with someone*, by injuring or repelling them with the brutal truth.

(The question didn't specify the cause of the falling out, but it's easy enough to surmise.)

Comment: This is a bad answer. You can fall out of favour for telling the truth, or for doing something bad. You get can get back in their good books be deceiving them or by genuinely doing something good.

Comment: @AndyT ~ so if my answer was more generic and multi-use, it would meet your approval.

Comment: Not the wording I'd use. I'd say "if you actually answered the question rather than made wild assumptions about what the question was "actually" asking, it would meet my approval". Currently your answer is the equivalent of "Q: What's the opposite of losing? A: Cheating".

Comment: @AndyT ~ Very general and nonspecific questions such as this one leave the reader a great deal of freedom and flexibility for creativity in thought and in writing. Obviously you share the same freedom, but **your own assumptions** just happen to be in **disagreement** with mine, and for some mysterious reason you feel overwhelmingly compelled to express your disapproval of my answer. And of course I realize you're perfectly free to do so, at your heart's content.

Comment: No, there is no need for assumption as to the meaning of "fall out of favour". What you have provided is not an opposite to it, it is a possible method for achieving the opposite to it.

Comment: @AndyT ~ It's all context, and of course you're free to try to impose your own personal opinion onto both the question and my answer. There is plenty of room for context with "fall out of favor", if you take the time to study the phrase. A person can 'fall out of favor' quite actively and intentionally. All they have to do is tell the truth, in many cases, to which I alluded in my answer. **To fall** is an active verb, so falling does not have to be unintentional. And I don't intend to reinforce stereotypes, as I'm sure some people might not feel the need to seek favors at all or n many cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74864/discussion-between-bread-and-andyt).